# Remove surrounding (table) layer if attribute=value (without direct attribute match!)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

im rather a beginner in XSLT, but have to solve the following and hope that maybe some of the bright minds from the StackOfJoel can help me: 
i have some working xslt code (1.1! cant use 2.0) that transfers XHTML into XML, the new requirement is:

- a certain div-element (with a specific attribute-value) is always contained in a table; the div should be transferred into a new element (NUREQ), and all surrounding table structure should be removed
- any other table should be preserved, and any other div should not be cut out, but be transformed themselves, to yet different elements (text)!

The problem is: i can not match the attribute directly in a template match, because i have to make the attributevalue-match case-insensitive (i use translate - is there any other method i could use directly in the templatematch? I know about question# 13620725 but its solution doesnt apply afaik)

So, as you can see in the example code & data, i have to find ONLY those divs that have the attribute "class" set to 'req' (or 'REQ', or 'reQ', etc..), transform them into a separate new element 'NUREQ', and remove the surrounding table. But for any other div (without this specific attribute), do the standard transformation into  element, but keep the table!

As you can see, i use translate() to make it caseinsensitive, therefor i cant use it in the templatematch.
Of course my normal XSL is way longer, filters and transforms many other elements & attributes, but i distilled it down to the essence.
Has anyone got ideas and can help me with that?

One xhtml test data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<head>  <title></title> <style type="text/css"/></head>
<body>
    <div class="somethingelse">inside std div with class</div>
    <div style="page-break-after">inside std div with style</div>
    <table><tbody><tr><th></th><td>
                Normal Table Cell should be kept
    </td></tr></tbody></table>

    <table><tr><td>
                 <div class="req">
                        22
                 </div>
    </td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>
                 <div class="somethingelse">
                     44
                 </div>
     </td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>
                 <div >
                    keep div with no class 55
                 </div>
    </td></tr></table>
    <div> some additional data </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Required Output (the strange formatting is just for brevity and visibility):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<segment>
<text class="somethingelse">inside std div with class</text>
<text style="page-break-after">inside std div with style</text>
    <table><tbody><tr><th/><td>
                    Normal Table Cell should be kept with table
    </td></tr></tbody></table>
    <NUREQ number="22"/>
    <table><tr><td>
                 <text class="somethingelse">
                     44
                 </text>
     </td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>
                 <text>
                    keep div with no class 55
                 </text>
    </td></tr></table>
<text> some additional data </text>
```

My current xslt file (without the required changes):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <segment>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </segment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(translate(@class, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'somethingelse')">
                <text class="{translate(@class, $uppercase, $lowercase)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(translate(@style, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'page-break-after')">
                <text style="{translate(@style, $uppercase, $lowercase)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <text>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="caption|tbody|thead|tr|table|th|td">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested around (more error than trial) around the following code snippet, but it still

- does not cut out the table around the div with the req-class (22 in the testdata)
- does not do the std required transformation div=>text for the other divs (44,55)

  ```
      <xsl:template match = "table/tr/td/div">
      <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="contains(translate(@class, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'req')">
                  <xsl:element name="NUREQ">
                      <xsl:attribute name="number">
                          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need XPath to do what you are looking for.  It must be done at the table element level, since that is the element that you are looking to prevent from showing, but only in the one instance.  I separated out a template for the table element now.

```
<xsl:template match="caption|tbody|thead|tr|th|td">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".//div[translate(@class, $uppercase, $lowercase)='req']">
            <xsl:element name="NUREQ">
                <xsl:attribute name="number">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.//div)" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="table">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right, thats exactly what i was looking for! 
The match has to be on the outer/table level, the level that has to be cut out.
Works like a charms!